# Convert bloc to lambda in JRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby

How does one convert a bloc to a lambda in jruby? Basically what is the jruby answer for this: [Ruby: convert proc to lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946603/ruby-convert-proc-to-lambda)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're running jruby 1.9-compatibly (e.g. `jruby --1.9 -S irb`), it should be the same:

```
my_proc = proc { |x| x }
my_lambda = lambda &my_proc
my_lambda.lambda?
# => true
```

Comment: A [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369553/jruby-is-ruby-lambda-syntax-not-an-important-consideration), and a [possibly helpful one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755900/how-to-make-jruby-1-6-default-to-ruby-1-9).